# Сортировка данных из json файла в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Есть https://teacode-recruitment-challenge.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/users.json, в нем хранятся данные, к примеру:

```
  [
   {"id":1,"first_name":"add","last_name":"add"},
   {"id":2,"first_name":"sfdf","last_name":"aad"}
  ]
```

Я вывожу список этих данных в свой компонент. Их видно, все прекрасно.

```
 function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const fetchContactsList = async() => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(URL)
      let contacts = await response.json()
      setContacts(contacts)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContactsList()
  }, [])


  return (
    <main>
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Search />
        <ContactsList contacts={contacts} />
      </Container>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Я хочу выводить отсортированный по фамилиям в алфавитном порядке список, и не могу понять, как этого добиться.
Куда мне нужно вписать sort(), чтобы получать уже отсортированный список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так попробуйте

```
function App() {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const fetchContactsList = async() => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(URL)
      let contacts = await response.json()
      contacts.sort( (a,b) => a.last_name.localeCompare(b.last_name))
      setContacts(contacts)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchContactsList()
  }, [])

return (
    <main>
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Search />
        <ContactsList contacts={contacts} />
      </Container>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я пропустила самое простое